# Tensorflow take mean of the elements of a masked tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, mean, mask, loss-function

To handle variable length input sequence, all the input sequences are padded to same length. This effects in calculating the value of loss. So a mask tensor is multiplied with the loss tensor to make the loss generated by padded elements 0. But in taking the mean of the loss using tf.math.reduce_mean or tf.keras.metrics.Mean, those padded elements has effects on the mean.

So my question is, How to take a mean of the masked loss in tensorflow?

For example:

```
t = [1, 2, 3]
t = pad(t, 6) # padding, now t = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
mask = [True, True, True, False, False, False]
loss = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.12, 0.2, 0.4] # notice padded elements contribute to loss
loss = loss * mask # loss = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now I want something like:

```
Mean(loss) = 0.6, which is (0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3) / 3
```

not something like:

```
Mean(loss) = 0.1, which is (0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0 + 0 + 0)/6
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer to this  [tensorflow google group](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/YUEKQi4YKyg)

Divide the reduce sum of the tensor by the reduce sum of the mask.

mean = tf.math.reduce_sum(t) / tf.math.reduce_sum(mask)